# expected a string, You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, web-frontend

I have this weird error, knowing that I organize well the files and export and import them carefully, but don't know why it throws me this! The code is ordred from components to the App render method.

**Item.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import './Global.css'

const Item = ({data, Icon}) => { 
  return (
    <div class='item'>
      <Icon />
      <h2>hhh{data}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Item;
```

**Nav.js**

```js
import React from "react";
import Logo from "./components/Logo"
import Item from './components/Item.js'
import Tweetbutton from './components/Tweetbutton'
import Profile from './components/Profile'

const Nav = () => {
    return (
        <div class='Nav'>
            <Logo />
            <div class='Nav__wrapper'>
                <Item data="home"/>
                <Item data="home"/>
                <Item data="home"/>
                <Item data="home"/>
                <Item data="home"/>
            </div>
            <Tweetbutton />
            <Profile />
        </div>
    );
}

export default Nav;
```

**Wrapper.js**

```js
import React from 'react'
import Nav from './High Level/Nav/Nav'
import './wrapper.css'

function Wrapper() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Nav />
    </div>
  )
}

export default Wrapper;
```

**App.js**

```js
import './App.css';
import Wrapper from './components/wrapper/wrapper';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Wrapper />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I tried to display the item icon and the data for example
*'home icon'* + *Home text*, but it throws me error

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.
You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports. Check the render method of Item. 
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. 
You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

Comment: What's the full error message?

Comment: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `Item`.
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Answer (score 1):

you didn't import the Icon component, also is not a component, you didn't do  prop drilling to Icon. You have to send to Item component the prop called "icon" from Nav comp.

Comment: OMG what a shame Error I did hahaha, it's really disgusting. Thank you som much I solved it, I appreciate your time